# Conditional Formatting for Google Sheets with Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1vpfzR2rm0P-LW_AC7lSe2HmuL_IKrK1XOnJ0R64xXXM/edit?usp=sharing

I'm trying to figure out how to use apps script to make the repetive number highlighted in yellow either disappear or put a white background and white text so that it isn't visible all the way down. I've tried setting custom formula in conditional format but kept getting error messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can understand your table, you need to add a condition `IF`:

```
=IF(E20<>"",sum(G19,E20-F20),"")
```

It will put into cell figures only if next cell is not empty.

Comment: if I wanted to do this in apps script could it be done? I've found in the past that when you drag formulas all the way down the sheet then it slows the load time tremendously. I messed around trying to piece together code that I found but never could get it to work the way your formula works.

Comment: It depends on how do you mean it should work. A custom formula wont work faster. `onedit()` trigger probably too. Fastest solution would be a not interactive script -- some function that will be run manually, but it doesn't make much sense in this case, I suppose. And I see no way to solve it via condition formatting.

Comment: Ok. I was just curious. Thanks again for your help!